# PHP echo JSON nested array values

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I want to echo all expanded_url and urls. `echo $name` prints **results** . `echo $value` doesn't print anything because of nested array. How do I echo all values?

```
$json ='{ "results" : [ { "entities" : 
[ { "urls" : [ { "expanded_url" : "http://www.google.com",
                    "url" : "http://t.co/WZnUf68j"
                  },  { "expanded_url" : "http://www.facebook.com",
                    "url" : "http://t.co/WZnUf68j"
                  }, { "expanded_url" : "http://www.twitter.com",
                    "url" : "http://t.co/WZnUf68j"
                  } ] } ],
        "from_user" : "A-user-name",
        "from_user_id" : 457304735,
        "text" : "Ich R U #BoysNoize #SuperRola"
      } ] }';
# $json_array = (array)(json_decode($json));

$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($data as $name => $value){
    echo $name.'<br>';
    echo $value; // NOT WORKING - HOW TO ECHO ALL VALUES    
}
```

Comment: isnt that what var_dump and print_r are for?  but if you must, you'll just have to approach it recursively.

Comment: you have array(array(array())); cannot do 1 foreach to trace that

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($data["results"][0]["entities"][0]["urls"] as $value){
    echo $value['expanded_url']."\n";
    echo $value['url']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a multidimensional array, you can loop through the various levels to reach where you want.

```
foreach($data['results'] as $item) {
    foreach($item['entities'] as $urls) {
        foreach($urls['urls'] as $element) {
            echo "expanded_url: {$element['expanded_url']} \n";
            echo "url: {$element['url']} \n";
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>***Note:*** *The reason I've done the various `foreach` loops is due to the fact that there may be different `results` or different `entities`, so it's better to loop, than to do `foreach($data["results"][0]["entities"][0]["urls"] as $value)`*</sup>

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://www.tehplayground.com/#T7tpiZI3Z)